# ExtJs 4 + PHP on deployment - class loading

Tags: php, zend-framework, extjs4, web-deployment

I am maintaining Zend application with ExtJS 3 based views. Recently, I am working on migrating to ExtJS 4 MVC based application.

**Background**

With ExtJS 3 I used to combine ExtJS library + all my JS files and include that in Zend layout (let's call that combine.js).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="combine.js"></script>
```

All I needed to do was to met dependencies in combined file.

Now, trying to accomplish ExtJS 4 MVC approach with Zend generating my views, I am running into multiple problems with the new Ext.Loader. My Zend layout consists of

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.application({
    name: 'demo',
    appFolder: 'app',
    controllers: [
    // controllers list here
    ],
    launch: function()
    {
    // viewport + page items
    }
});
</script>
```

Moreover, in HEAD section I still maintain the same approach to include one combined file (ExtJS 4 library + all my js files). In theory, I have all js dependencies met since I include the whole library before my code.

**Problem**

I am running into multiple problems with new class loading mechanism.
Let's assume I have only one controller with one view and one store on ExtJS side:

```
Ext.define('demo.myModule.controller.MyGrid', function() {
   extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
   stores: [ 'demo.myModule.store.MyStore' ],
   views: [ 'demo.myModule.view.MyStore' ]
   ...
});
```

Rendering such page ends up with Ext.Loader trying to fetch not existing resource :

```
GET http://myPage/demo/myModule/store/MyStore.js?_dc=1390226857962 404 (Not Found)
```

Disabling Ext.Loader ends up with :

```
Uncaught Error: Ext.Loader is not enabled, so dependencies cannot be resolved dynamically. Missing required class: demo.myModule.controller.MyGrid
```

Since ExtJS 4 is a really popular library, someone must have hit the same stumbling block before. What is the proper way to tackle such problem ?
BTW. I am asking that question having already spent couple of days on ExtJS documentation + official tutorials, tried Sencha CMD but I fail to get what the exact problem is.

**EDIT:**
I have added a sample project showing the problem: https://github.com/mirfilip/extjs-zend. You can see app.js containing simple class demo.myModule.view.Panel. In application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml you can see that the whole library + app.js is loaded (in order). When you try to render the project it will show the blank page. However, if you go to layout and uncomment lines 23-33 (and comment out appending of app.js in line 11) and render, it works well. The only difference is where my class is defined in. There should be no possible time race between classes as Ext.application creation is wrapped it Ext.onReady. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Zend Studio, so I cannot give a specific answer. I will just show you my code, how I integrate ExtJs into my own homebrewed framework.

This is the html code on my development site, which will use `Ext.Loader` to load the classes dynamically.

```
<!-- <x-compile> -->
    <!-- <x-bootstrap> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
        <script src="ext/ext-dev.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- </x-bootstrap> -->
    <script src="ext/locale/ext-lang-fr.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
<!-- </x-compile> -->
```

This will then compile to :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/Mb-all.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

This snipped is found in the `build/production/MyApp/index.php` folder. I have then a build script that takes this file and copies it where it should be for the php framework to work.

I hope this will give you an idea to solve your specific problem.

Important: app.js is a autogenerated file by sencha cmd. **It is not the same thing in the development environment and in the test environment.**

In the development it just contains this text:

```
/*
    This file is generated and updated by Sencha Cmd. You can edit this file as
    needed for your application, but these edits will have to be merged by
    Sencha Cmd when upgrading.
*/

Ext.application({
    name: 'Mb',
    extend: 'Mb.Application',
    autoCreateViewport: true
});
```

In the production envrionment it contains the full, minified javascript source of the app.

Comment: I don't use Zend Studio as IDE either. If I understood you correctly, this is what you do:
1. Create .html file with your first snippet (I suppose ext-dev.js to be the framework and app.js to be your code).
2. Point Sencha CMD to that .html, it compiles to second snippet. Then you include this snippet in your framework' entrypoint (would be the Zend Layout in my case).

So the bottomline is to create a temporary .html file with library + my JavaScript code included, run Sencha CMD on it, produce new css & js files, include them in your framework. Do I get it right?

Comment: Yes, you got it. The only thing is that app.js is not what you think. I edited the post to explain better.

Comment: Thank you, the idea seems clearer for me now. I will certainly try it and come back here. Thank you.

Comment: Let's talk about development environment for a second. My approach is exactly the same as yours. The difference is that you use Ext.Loader and I combine everything. I understand the benefits of dynamic loading but at the moment I am unable to introduce Sencha Cmd to produce production ready app. Let's assume you turn off Ext.Loader for development. What happens when you combine all your sources (e.g. using YUI Compressor) ? What about when you use Sencha Cmd to do it ?

Comment: I think, combining all sources will work, if you respect the order defined by your `requires:[]` statements in the class definitions. In fact determine the correct order of inclusion is one complicated thing, Sencha Cmd does for you.

Comment: Could you examine my sample app (see Edited in question) ? There is only one class extending Ext.panel.Panel. No requires needed. When I uncomment the declaration to be directly above the usage - it works. Having that loaded via <script> - it does not. I am going through docs once again and I'm left with idea that there has to be sth wrong with scoping.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to indicate paths to Ext classes before your combined app js file. I'm using paths relative to domain root ('/app' not 'app').

```
<script>
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    paths : {
        'demo' : '/app'
    },
    enabled: true
});
</script>

<script src="combine.js" />
```

Comment: The point is I do not want to use Ext.Loader. By including the combined file (with bunch my Ext.Define('my.namespace.here')) I have met all the dependencies. By the time the page loads, you can do console.log(my.namespace.here) and you can see the class.

To sum up, I have combine.js with all the Ext.defines. I think I have come closer to the problem. Assuming I have one Ext.define extending Ext.panel.Panel in my combine.js, it will:
1. try to load Panel.js - with Ext.Loader enabled (and fail)
2. display white page without any error - with Ext.Loader disabled

Comment: You could enable Ext.Loader for debugging purposes. If it loads some ext classes even if you have combine.js it probably means that that class has been not defined in time (wrong order in the combine.js). Playing with order of classes definitions usually solves the issue.

Comment: I though so too. Enabling Ext.Loader really does try to load classes. It fails because I deal with very custom files structure where one class per file rule is not followed. I also tried to split the combine file, include the library first and later my app.js which, for debugging purposes, contains only one class which extends  Ext.panel.Panel. Order of including files tells that there should be no time race between classes. It still fails. I will prepare a demo project and upload to github so that you get better idea what I am up to.